# Javascript: Auto Calculate dropdown price*quantity input

Tags: javascript, html

This code should allow users to choose the size and quantity of banners and the code will automatically calculate the price they have to pay. I tried so many ways but it failed. Below is the code that I had done

```js
function calculateAmount() {

  var selFrst = parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
  var selScnd = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);

  var tot_price;

  if (selFrst == 120) {
    tot_price = selFrst * selScnd;
  } else if (selFrst == 80) {
    tot_price = selFrst * selScnd;

  } else if (selFrst == 64) {
    tot_price = selFrst * selScnd;

  }

  /*display the result*/

  document.getElementById("tot_amount").value = tot_price;
}
```

```html
<form id="banner" method="post" action="">

  <table border="1" width="50%">
    <col style="width:15%">
    <col style="width:35%">
    <!--form title-->
    <tr>
      <!--general-->
      <th colspan="2">General</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td>Size</td>
      <td>
        <select name="size" id="size" onchange="calculateAmount()">
          <option value="0" disabled selected>--Choose Size--</option>
          <option value="120">4x15</option>
          <option value="80">4x10</option>
          <option value="64">4x8</option>

        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="points" name="points" step="1" min="1" max="499" onchange="calculateAmount()">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Order Total:RM</td>
      <td><input name="tot_amount" id="tot_amount" type="text" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <!--end payment-->

  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have used id=quantity, but named quantity as point

```
<input type="number" id="points" name="points" step="1" min="1" max="499" onchange="calculateAmount()">
```

You can see id="points" in the above line, and in the javascript you have used "quantity"

```
var selScnd = parseInt(document.getElementById("quantity").value);
```

And cannot guess what the if-else is actually written for, every condition is doing the same work. So remove the if-else. Try the code below.

```
    function calculateAmount() {

        var selFrst = parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
        var selScnd = parseInt(document.getElementById("points").value);

        var tot_price = selFrst * selScnd;

        /*display the result*/

        document.getElementById("tot_amount").value = tot_price;
    }
```

Comment: I try edit like you suggest but it still didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Variable `selScnd` should be selected with the id `point`, not width `quantity` since there is no such id as `quantity`. In other words there is a typo in your Code.

Your code should be like this:

```js
function calculateAmount() {

  var selFrst = parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
  var selScnd = parseInt(document.getElementById("points").value);

  var tot_price;

  if (selFrst == 120) {
    tot_price = selFrst * selScnd;
  } else if (selFrst == 80) {
    tot_price = selFrst * selScnd;

  } else if (selFrst == 64) {
    tot_price = selFrst * selScnd;

  }

  /*display the result*/

  document.getElementById("tot_amount").value = tot_price;
}
```

```html
<form id="banner" method="post" action="">

  <table border="1" width="50%">
    <col style="width:15%">
    <col style="width:35%">
    <!--form title-->
    <tr>
      <!--general-->
      <th colspan="2">General</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td>Size</td>
      <td>
        <select name="size" id="size" onchange="calculateAmount()">
          <option value="0" disabled selected>--Choose Size--</option>
          <option value="120">4x15</option>
          <option value="80">4x10</option>
          <option value="64">4x8</option>

        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="points" name="points" step="1" min="1" max="499" onchange="calculateAmount()">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Order Total:RM</td>
      <td><input name="tot_amount" id="tot_amount" type="text" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <!--end payment-->

  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: can you please tell me what the if-else is doing here?

Comment: @SubhashisPandey As you can see every option in select input has a value attribute (value="120", value="80", and value="64"), he used if-else to compare those values. and then those value are multiplied with second input/variable not 4x10 etc because we selected values of input

Comment: "he used if-else to compare those values" I don't think "SABRINA" is a "he"

Comment: ??is that a big deal?

Answer (score 1):

The id of the second div is wrong, also, you should compute the price only when both input are chosen:

```js
function calculateAmount() {

  var selFrst = parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
  var selScnd = parseInt(document.getElementById("points").value);

  var tot_price;

  if(selScnd && selFrst) {
    if (selFrst == 120) {
      tot_price = selFrst * selScnd;
    } else if (selFrst == 80) {
      tot_price = selFrst * selScnd;

    } else if (selFrst == 64) {
      tot_price = selFrst * selScnd;

    }
    document.getElementById("tot_amount").value = tot_price;
  }

  /*display the result*/


}
```

```html
<form id="banner" method="post" action="">

  <table border="1" width="50%">
    <col style="width:15%">
    <col style="width:35%">
    <!--form title-->
    <tr>
      <!--general-->
      <th colspan="2">General</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td>Size</td>
      <td>
        <select name="size" id="size" onchange="calculateAmount()">
          <option value="0" disabled selected>--Choose Size--</option>
          <option value="120">4x15</option>
          <option value="80">4x10</option>
          <option value="64">4x8</option>

        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="points" name="points" step="1" min="1" max="499" onchange="calculateAmount()">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Order Total:RM</td>
      <td><input name="tot_amount" id="tot_amount" type="text" readonly></td>
    </tr>
    <!--end payment-->

  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function calculateAmount() {

  var selFrst = parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
  var selScnd = parseInt(document.getElementById("points").value);
  var tot_price;

  if ([120, 80, 64].includes(selFrst)) {
    tot_price = selFrst * selScnd;
  }

  /*display the result*/

  document.getElementById("tot_amount").value = tot_price;
}
```

```html
<form id="banner" method="post" action="">

  <table border="1" width="50%">
    <col style="width:15%">
    <col style="width:35%">
    <!--form title-->
    <tr>
      <!--general-->
      <th colspan="2">General</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>

      <td>Size</td>
      <td>
        <select name="size" id="size">
          <option value="0" disabled selected>--Choose Size--</option>
          <option value="120">4*15</option>
          <option value="80">4*10</option>
          <option value="64">4*8</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Quantity</td>
      <td>
        <input type="number" id="points" name="points" step="1" min="1" max="499">
      </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Order Total:RM</td>
      <td><input name="tot_amount" id="tot_amount" type="text" readonly onfocus="calculateAmount()"></td>
    </tr>
    <!--end payment-->

  </table>
</form>
```

Like @swebdev said "Variable `selScnd` should be selected with its id `point` because there is no such id as `quantity`.

You can put the values (120,80,64) in an array so that you can add more values easily without repeating the if-else.

Finally, instead of using `onchange=""` twice, you may use `onfocus=""` in that last read-only input box. :)

Answer (score 0):

Still fail

```
    <table border="1"width="50%">
        <col style="width:15%">
        <col style="width:35%">
        <!--form title-->  
        <tr>

            <td>Size</td>
            <td><select name="size" id="size" onchange="calculateAmount()">
                <option value="0" disabled selected>--Choose Size--</option>
                <option value="120">4x15</option>
                <option value="80">4x10</option>
                <option value="64">4x8</option>
                
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>
                <input type="number" id="quantity" name="quantity" step="1"
                 min="1" max="499" onchange="calculateAmount()">
            </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr> 
            <td>Order Total:RM</td>
            <td><input name="tot_amount" id="tot_amount" type="text" readonly></td>
        </tr><!--end payment-->

    </table>
</form>


<script>

    function calculateAmount() {

    var selFrst = parseInt(document.getElementById("size").value);
    var selScnd = parseInt(document.getElementById("points").value);

    var tot_price = selFrst * selScnd;

    /*display the result*/

    document.getElementById("tot_amount").value = tot_price;
}
    </script> <!--end table-->
```

Comment: instead of posting your query as answer, you should add comment or update your question.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.